# Is it posible to use EJB for manage container transactions without persistance context?

Tags: java, ejb, jta

I'm trying to manage transactions in my app using JTA Transaction Containers in an EJB, but for data access I don use JPA. The data access is with DAOs which use JDBC connection directly.

I've included `jta = "true"` in my datasource config.

I've tried to make happen rollback from a transaction by inserting 2 elements with the same primary key this way:

```java
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class EjbGenero {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void testTransaccion() throws Exception {
        DtoGenero genero1 = new DtoGenero();
        genero1.setTipoSexo(3);
        genero1.setDescripcionSexo("genero3");

        DtoGenero genero2 = new DtoGenero();
        genero2.setTipoSexo(4);
        genero2.setDescripcionSexo("genero4");

        DtoGenero genero3 = new DtoGenero();
        genero3.setTipoSexo(4);
        genero3.setDescripcionSexo("genero5");

        DaoGenero dao = new DaoGenero();
        dao.con = SingletonConnection.getInstance().getConnection();

        dao.create(genero1);  
        dao.create(genero2); 
        dao.create(genero3); 


    }
}
```

But didn't work. This just throws sql exception and doesn't rollback the transaction.

I'm also aware that only RuntimeExceptions provoke rollback, so I've tried this:

```java
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class EjbGenero {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void testTransaccion() throws Exception {
        DtoGenero genero1 = new DtoGenero();
        genero1.setTipoSexo(3);
        genero1.setDescripcionSexo("genero3");

        DtoGenero genero2 = new DtoGenero();
        genero2.setTipoSexo(4);
        genero2.setDescripcionSexo("genero4");

        DaoGenero dao = new DaoGenero();
        dao.con = SingletonConnection.getInstance().getConnection();

        dao.create(genero1);  
        dao.create(genero2); 

        throw new RuntimeException();

    }
}
```

Didn't worked.

Finally I´ve read that is posible to force rollback by using the session context this way:

```java
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class EjbGenero extends EJB {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void testTransaccion() {
        try {
            DtoGenero genero1 = new DtoGenero();
        genero1.setTipoSexo(3);
        genero1.setDescripcionSexo("genero3");

        DtoGenero genero2 = new DtoGenero();
        genero2.setTipoSexo(4);
        genero2.setDescripcionSexo("genero4");

        DtoGenero genero3 = new DtoGenero();
        genero3.setTipoSexo(4);
        genero3.setDescripcionSexo("genero5");

        DaoGenero dao = new DaoGenero();
        dao.con = SingletonConnection.getInstance().getConnection();

        dao.create(genero1);  
        dao.create(genero2); 
        dao.create(genero3);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            context.setRollbackOnly();
        }

    }
}
```

But it also failed to rollback.

All the implementations I've seen used JPA as a `@PersistenceContext`, which I think is the reason why this didn't worked.

Can anyone help me to make this work without JPA or confirm that is not posible?

Please let me know If my question is not clear or I can provide more details to understand It better.

Also let me know if you think there is another posible way to use JTA without JPA.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is most probably with `SingletonConnection.getInstance().getConnection()`. You need to get a connextion from the DataSource managed by the EJB container. The DataSource should be injected in the DAO. And every connection you get should be closed, thanks to a finally block or the try-with-resources statement. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html

Comment: Worked perffect when injecting the DataSource! Thanks.